# How to create group of group

Tags: c#, linq

I have two classes

```
public class Parent
{
    public string EmployeeKey { get; set; }      

    public IEnumerable<ChildClass> ChildClassCollection { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass
{
    public DateTime? SentData { get; set; }
}
```

What I want is `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, IGrouping<DateTime?, ChildClass>>>`

what I have is a collection of `Parent` class object
`IEnumerable<Parent>`

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

`IGrouping<DateTime?, ChildClass>>` represents one key-collection pair, and in general case you are not guaranteed to have only one. If you meant `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime?, ChildClass>>>>` then here are some possibilities:

Personally I would go with dictionary of dictionaries:

```cs
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime?, List<ChildClass>>> dictionary = parents
    .GroupBy(parent => parent.EmployeeKey)
    .ToDictionary(
        gr => gr.Key,
        gr => gr
            .SelectMany(p => p.ChildClassCollection)
            .GroupBy(child => child.SentData)
            .ToDictionary(childGr => childGr.Key, childGr => childGr.ToList()));
```

But you can also use lookups:

```cs
ILookup<string, ILookup<DateTime?, ChildClass>> lookup = parents
    .GroupBy(parent => parent.EmployeeKey)
    .Select(grouping => (grouping.Key, Lookup: grouping.SelectMany(p => p.ChildClassCollection).ToLookup(child => child.SentData)))
    .ToLookup(tuple => tuple.Key, tuple => tuple.Lookup);
```

[`ILookup<TKey,TElement>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.ilookup-2?view=net-8.0) is `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>`.

And as you can see the "trick" used in both cases -`SelectMany` on the "second" level.